# How do I initialize a vector of objects using both vector and the objects constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, initialization

How do I initialize
`std::vector<std::ifstream>` from an existing `std::vector<std::string>` which are the names of the files that are intended to open?

Without an initialization of `vector`, I can do it using

```
std::vector<std::string> input_file_names;
// Populate the vector with names of files that needs to open.
// ...
std::vector<std::ifstream> input_files_;
for (auto const & input_file_name : input_file_names) {
  input_files_.emplace_back(input_file_name);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your existing solution? I don't think you can do it using the constructor unless you know at compile-time how many names you have.

Comment: @KevinBallard I need to put them in a custom class, and it is more convenient to have them in the initializer of the class constructor instead of the constructor body.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: Well, as I said, I don't think that's possible unless you know at compile-time how many elements there are. So I think you need to stick with a constructor body. The only option is to factor this out into a function `std::vector<std::ifstream> (*)(std::vector<std::string>)` and call that in your initializer, but that's not going to save you anything.

Comment: Since [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) isn't even copyable, I'm curious how your vector is going to fare in the first place. It is *move* constructible, but that may not work out like you hope.

Comment: @KevinBallard Why does it have anything to do with compile-time? Isn't a vector can be initialize out of another vector of random number of same type elements? `std::vector<std::string> words2(words1.begin(), words1.end());`

Comment: @WiSaGaN: Of the same type, sure. I didn't know `std::ifstream` had a constructor that took a `std::string` and opened the file, so I didn't realize sheu's solution would work.

Comment: @KevinBallard I didn't know either. Right after the comment above, sheu posted the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In c++11, the `std::ifstream` constructor will take a `std::string` as a parameter.  String that together with the `std::vector` copy constructor, and this should work:

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames;
std::vector<std::ifstream> files(filenames.begin(), filenames.end());
```

Comment: Range copy constructor FTW.  Just remember to compile in c++11 mode  :-)

Comment: **1** If it takes a parameter, it's not the default constructor. **2** The `ifstream` constructors taking file names (either as `string` or as `char*`) are explicit, so you can't convert the filenames implicitly to `ifstream`s.

Comment: @ArneMertz: alright, I trimmed off the "default" bit for you.  As to the second bit: starting in c++0x, `std::ifstream` *does* have a constructor that takes a `std::string` parameter; no implicit conversion necessary.

Comment: @ArneMertz, It seems they actually are not marked `explicit`. I thought they would be as well.

Comment: @sheu, chris: The conversion from std::string to std::ifstream would be an implicit conversion as well, and the constructor indeed *is* marked explicit (**§27.9.1.7,3**). However, `vector`'s range constructor explicitly calls the conversion, so I was wrong: **§23.2.3** states that in this case, `ifstream` shall be `EmplaceConstructible` from `string`, which it is from **§23.2.1,13** since `std::allocator` is used in the target vector.

Comment: @ArneMertz, Interesting, cppreference left that detail out.

Comment: Yep, *left*. It puzzled me as well, so I just looked it up in the standard and fixed it ;)